# Wait for network connection before executing a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a bat to run a python script when logging on Windows.

```
start C:\python34\pythonw.exe D:\myscript.py
```

The myscript.py requires some Internet activities, and sometimes it can't be executed properly because the internet connection has not been activated immediately after logging on Windows.

How to make sure myscript runs only after the Internet connection has established?

Answer (score 4):

Just ping a server such as www.google.com
Then you just have to check the answer with errorlevel like this:

```
ping www.google.com -n 1 -w 1000
if errorlevel 0 start C:\python34\pythonw.exe D:\myscript.py
if errorlevel 1 echo No network
```

**EDIT:**
Added a couple lines of code.

**YET ANOTHER EDIT:**
A much better way of doing it would be like this:

```
:ping
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 1000 > nul
set target=www.google.com
ping %target% -n 1 | find "TTL="
if errorlevel==1 goto ping
start C:\python34\pythonw.exe D:\myscript.py
```

The first ping is there to add a 1 sec (1000 millisec) delay so we don't overload.

Comment: What your answer does is it prints "No network" when there is no network connection, but it won't ensure that the myscript runs only under a network connection.

Comment: "destination not reachable" will also give an errorlevel of 0  (false positive).

Comment: That must be because you get a response, but not a positive. I have a script for checkinh the actual response at home. I'll try remember posting it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set target=www.google.com
echo Waiting for connection..
:ping
<nul set /p strTemp=.
timeout 2 > NUL
ping %target% -n 1 | find "TTL="
if errorlevel==1 goto ping
echo.
echo Connected
REM start somthing
REM start C:\_soft\putty.exe
```

Comment: This may be a correct answer, but it’d be useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who may not be familiar with the syntax. Further, it can help reduce the need for follow-up questions. Would you mind updating your comment with additional details?

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me, may it will help to you also!

```
@ECHO OFF
:loop
PING google.com | FIND "time=" > NUL
echo waiting.....
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto loop 

ECHO You have active connection to the Internet

REM you can add your scripts to run after internet connection success

pause
```

Now I am trying to show as the loading in bat, the above code will print waiting.... until the connection is a success

Comment: this code claims I have no internet connection (`ping` reports `Antwort von 172.217.18.100: Bytes=32 Zeit=12ms TTL=121`, (there is no string `time=`)).  That's why the other answers search for the string `TTL=`, which is independent of the language and the only international reliable thing with `ping`.